# How to make a dynamic range in Excel, depending on the rows of data on another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an Excel Macro that among other things autofills an array formula in a dynamic range let's say P2:P(x) where (x) is the number of rows that have data in another column, let's say O. I am using the `COUNTA` function but either that's not the appropriate approach, or my syntax is off, cause I keep getting a syntax error.

Below is the aforementioned code, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Range("E1").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "custom id"
Range("E2").Select
   Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=TEXTJOIN("""",TRUE,IFERROR((MID(RC[1],ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(RC[1]))),1)*1),""""))"
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
Range("P1").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "amount"
Range("P2").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NUMBERVALUE(RC[-1],"","",""."")"
Range("P3").Select
Range("P2").Select
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P" & COUNTA(C[-1])), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("P2:P" & COUNTA(C[-1])).Select
Range("E2").Select
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & COUNTA(C[1])), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E" & COUNTA(C[1]).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LastRow to find the last row of data in another column, in your case X, enter the formula into first column (E) and then autofill formula down to LastRow :

Repeat the below for the other columns.

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E2").FormulaArray":"" 'Enter your formula between quotation marks, if not array then change to Range("E2").Formula = ""
Range("E2").AutoFill Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just to understand the scope of the code used (fairly new to coding), you used the LastRow to find the last row of data, which you then used as a variable to denominate the last cell of the range to autofill?
Again, you are a lifesaver.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Glad it helped.